# how do I find median in sql (code question)

Tags: mysql, median, table-alias

I find answers below:
Select round(S.LAT_N,4) mediam from station S where (select count(Lat_N) from station where Lat_N < S.LAT_N ) = (select count(Lat_N) from station where Lat_N > S.LAT_N)

I'm confused at where S come from??

Comment: `S` is an alias of 'station`. The `FROM` clause is defining it as that alias.

Answer (score 0):

`S` is an alias of `station`. The `FROM` clause is defining `station` as that alias `S`. With it defined this way `station.{field}` isn't valid, only `S.{field}` is.